# How to create VPN connection in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, vpn, authentication

I have the VPN credentials for VPN connection which I successfully use in Windows. But I cannot create the vpn connection in Linux Mint.

I have the connection with vpn server from the terminal when I provide the `ping` command - so the connection exists.
But when I did create the Vpn connection in the following window:

[image]

and try to connect to server - I did get the error message

[image]

How to correctly connect to VPN remote server in Linux mint?